# How to get excel live data feed in python for automation

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I got an live data feed from FYERS one app and I want to automate the trade with excel in python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Try using python

- Extract the data from python
- Use Fyers API to authenticate the python app
- Use [fyers API](https://fyers.in/api)
- For reference checkout [Python - Fyers API](https://github.com/katmakhan/python-course/blob/master/Live%20Stock%20Data/Fyers%20API/fyers_api.py)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).